# Don't understand output order of thread constructor, start and run methods

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

Why does this code always print this?

```
in start oops
in ctor oops
```

And doesn't call the `run` method even though the thread already has been started. when thread started firstly start method called then run.

```
class MyThread extends Thread {
    public MyThread(String name) {
    this.setName(name);
    start();
    System.out.println("in ctor " + getName());
  }
  public void start() {
    System.out.println("in start " + getName());
   }
  public void run() {
    System.out.println("in run " + getName());
  }
}


class Test {

   public static void main(String []args) {
            new MyThread("oops");
            }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Thread.start is overriden and is never actually called. Try to add super.start(); to MyTread.start

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have not started a `Thread` as such rather you have just created an instance of the class MyThread which extends `Thread`.

To start a method you need to invoke `start()` method from `Thread` class. Here you have overridden the method but did not call the actual method from super class. So you need to fix this as:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread myThread = new MyThread("oops");
        myThread.start();
    }
}

class MyThread extends Thread {
    public MyThread(String name) {
        this.setName(name);
        this.start();
        System.out.println("in ctor " + getName());
    }
    public void start() {
        super.start();
        System.out.println("in start " + getName());
    }
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        System.out.println("in run " + getName());
    }
}
```

On a side note you should always prefer implementing `Runnable` (or `Callable`) for multi-threading requirement.